# effectively work with files in c

Tags: c, file, data-structures

I want to code small database in c, The data will be stored in files, the program will read and write structures to the file.
How do I create this kind of program effectively?
for example, reading from file one struct at a time will not be efficient(cause of many read/write to hdd). So I need to take part of the file to the memory manipulate the data then write it to the file(less read/writes to hdd), but this might cause a problem if the file is too big, so there is a new question how much of that file will be loaded to memory each time..

So its big topic, but im looking for effective method but some what easy at the same time, Im not looking for max efficiency.
note: easy for me is one struct at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: even if i do that?`while(1){
                fread(&cli,sizeof(Client),1,fp);
                if(!feof(fp)){...` i dont think this is efficient...

Comment: No, fopen, then fseek to the record you want to write, fwrite it and fclose.

Comment: with fseek i still need to search the record i want to so i loop thru the file, not efficient.

Comment: Ok, use sqlite, see answer below.

Comment: I know what is sqlite.. I'm looking for solution without already coded database.

Comment: How to code your small database depends a lot on what you want it to do and what kind of data you'll be storing. Are the records fixed length? Do you need a way to quickly find a record based on a key? How many records? Will you need to add, delete, and update records? "A database" can be many things. Without specifying more clearly what you want, it's impossible to provide recommendations.

Comment: If you're looking for simple key-lookup for your structs, the ndbm family will help.  "man dbm_open"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "reading from file one struct at a time will not be efficient(cause of many read/write to hdd)"

This is a big assumption, which is likely wrong. Or at least not nearly as bad as you make it out to be.

The C standard I/O library performs buffering, and and so does your operating system.

Write the program to do the data transfers in whatever unit is convenient from the point of view of clear program organization, and let the buffering do the work of aggregating for efficiency.

Even if the program does perform poorly, I wouldn't jump to the conclusion that it needs to be majorly restructured. Tuning some system parameters could be the way to go. Or perhaps just a few lines of platform-specific code to give a hint to the operating system that could improve performance. On a POSIX platform, see if you have the function `fadvise` for instance. (You can retrieve the file descriptor from a `FILE *` stream using the `fileno` function.)

Comment: what do you think about this code in terms of efficiency, `while(1){ fread(&cli,sizeof(Client),1,fp); if(!feof(fp)){...`

Comment: @MikeL What I think is that `fread` has a return value that should be tested, and that `sizeof cli` is a perfectly good way to get the size of `cli`, rather than referring to its declared type, which could change. But in terms of efficiency, there isn't anything wrong with using `fread` for one structure.